# Did Sri Rama visit Hatya Haran teertha (Prabhaskar Teertha) to purify himself?

Tags: scripture, temple, rama

Did Sri Rama visit Hatya Haran teertha (Prabhaskar Teertha) to purify himself of the sin of Brahma Hatya due to killing of Raavana?

The Sthala Purana of Hatyaharan Teertha as it is popularly known in Uttar Pradesh is about 25 kms from Naimisharanya Teertha. Namisharanya in Sitapur District UP is about 150 kms from Lucknow and 180 kms from Ayodhya. The Sthala claims it to be Prabhaskar Kshetra.

There is a mention of Prabhaskar Teertha in Shiva Purana. According to the story,  In SatyaYuga Shiva and His Consort came to wander around Naimisharanya. The forests were so serene and calm that Shiva sat down to meditate and Parvati wandered around the forest.  Suddenly she felt thirsty, but finding no water asked the Devas to fetch some for Her. Surya Deva appeared and offered his kamandalu to Parvati to drink and while She was drinking a few drops fell on the ground and became a tank – teerthasthala.  When Shiva and Parvati were ready to leave the place, Shiva named the Sthala as Prabhaskar Kshetra.

It is said that in Treta Yuga, after defeating and killing Raavana, on His way back to Ayodhya, Sri Rama came to Hatyaharan Teertha to wash away the sin of Brahmahathya He had incurred in slaying Raavana [if true, then Raavana was not an Asura as made out but a Brahmin]. I find no mention of this visit or Praayaschitta in Valmiki Ramayana.

**My questions are:**

**(a)   Did Sri Rama visit Hatyaharan Teertha on His way back to Ayodhya?**

**(b)   Is this teertha indeed the Prabhaskara Kshetra referred to in Shiva Purana?**

**(c)   In which scriptures / epics is the story of Sri Rama performing praayaschitta for Brahmahathya at Prabhaskara Kshetra described?**

Comment: Rama installed Ramanatha linga (Rameswaram) to expiate from sin of Brahma hatya as per Skanda Purana.

Comment: But as per Valmiki Ramayana, Ramanatha Ramalinga idol was installed by Rama when he was going to Sri Lanka and before the construction of the bridge to Lanka. There is no reference in Ramayana of Rama coming back to Rameshwaram on his return to Ayodhya.

Comment: Possibly due to kalpa bheda.

Comment: there is no brahmahatya for rAma - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53168/21696